# How to set field to match values of array in Flowjs?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Given some frozen array object meant to represent possible values for a form field.

```
const FROZEN_LIST = Object.freeze(['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'])
```

How do I set the form object definition to ONLY accept the possible values defined in this array for this field key in Flow.js?

```
// @flow
import {FROZEN_LIST} from (...)

type FormData = {
  fieldKey: Array<string>, // this is not desirable because I want it to be more specific.
  fieldKey: typeof FROZEN_LIST // is this how its done?
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> In situations like this one, you can leverage the $Keys operator. [$Keys](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys)

In your situation:

```js
// @flow
import {FROZEN_LIST} from (...)

type FormData = {
  fieldKey: $Keys<typeof FROZEN_LIST.reduce((r,i)=>({...r,...{[i]:i}}), {})>
}
```

Let me know if it worked.

It would be better if you could change the original `FROEZEN_LIST`:

```js
const FROZEN_LIST = Object.freeze({'Value1':'Value1', 'Value2',:'Value2', 'Value3':'Value3'})
```

```js
// @flow
import {FROZEN_LIST} from (...)

type FormData = {
  fieldKey: $Keys<typeof FROZEN_LIST>
}
```

You can follow this instruction too: [Union from array literal](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/961#issuecomment-410557152)